# using join and group by clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use `group by` in my query:

```
 $sql = "select count(T1.coupon_id) as current_user,T1.coupon_id,T1.shadyab_profit,T1.seri
         from (select tractions.*,traction_details.* from traction_details,tractions
            where tractions.id = traction_details.tr_id
                AND (traction_details.sell_start_date >= '2015-09-10 01:00:00')
                AND confirm=2 AND traction_details.adviser = 7) T1
         group by T1.coupon_id,T1.seri,T1.shadyab_profit
        ";

  $result = mysql_query($sql) ;
  var_dump($result);
```

but it return `false`.

where is my wrong ?

**updated**

```
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'current_user,T1.coupon_id,T1.shadyab_profit,T1.seri from (SELECT
> tr' at line 1



 $sql = "select count(T1.coupon_id) as current_user,T1.coupon_id,T1.shadyab_profit,T1.seri
         from (SELECT tractions.*,traction_details.* 
           FROM traction_details
           INNER JOIN tractions ON tractions.id = traction_details.tr_id
           WHERE (traction_details.sell_start_date >= '2015-09-10 01:00:00')
           AND [table_name_it_belongs].confirm=2 
           AND traction_details.adviser = 7) T1
           group by T1.coupon_id,T1.seri,T1.shadyab_profit
        ";

  $result = mysql_query($sql) ;
echo mysql_error();
```

tractions table :

[image]

traction_details table :

[image]

@updated :

```
SELECT COUNT(coupon_id), coupon_id, shadyab_profit, seri
FROM traction_details td INNER JOIN
     tractions t
     ON t.id = td.tr_id
WHERE (td.sell_start_date >= '2015-09-10 01:00:00') AND
       td.adviser = 7
GROUP BY coupon_id, seri, shadyab_profit, seri
            ";

      $result = mysql_query($sql) ;
 echo mysql_error();
var_dump($result);
       echo "=>>".count($result);
```

**I got this error :**

```
Column 'seri' in field list is ambiguous
```

**solved:**

```
     $query = $this->db->query("select count(T1.coupon_id) as `current_user`,T1.coupon_id,T1.shadyab_profit,T1.seri
      from (SELECT tractions.coupon_id,traction_details.*
        FROM traction_details
          INNER JOIN tractions ON tractions.id = traction_details.tr_id
          WHERE (traction_details.sell_end_date BETWEEN '$start_sell' AND '$end_sell')
          AND traction_details.adviser = 7 AND  tractions.succ=1 AND tractions.expired !=$adviser_id) T1
         group by T1.coupon_id,T1.seri,T1.shadyab_profit
        ");
```

Comment: Use mysqli_ or PDO.  These are supported interfaces.  Also, learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Call `mysql_error($link)` to see what is happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery should be with `JOIN` -

```
SELECT tractions.*,traction_details.* 
FROM traction_details
INNER JOIN tractions ON tractions.id = traction_details.tr_id
WHERE (traction_details.sell_start_date >= '2015-09-10 01:00:00')
AND traction_details.confirm=2 
AND traction_details.adviser = 7
```

**Update**

`current_user` is a function. You cant use that this way. You can use backticks or can change the name.

```
SELECT COUNT(tractions.coupon_id) as `current_user`,tractions.coupon_id,traction_details.shadyab_profit,traction_details.seri 
FROM traction_details
INNER JOIN tractions ON tractions.id = traction_details.tr_id
WHERE (traction_details.sell_start_date >= '2015-09-10 01:00:00')
AND traction_details.confirm=2 
AND traction_details.adviser = 7
group by tractions.coupon_id,traction_details.seri,traction_details.shadyab_profit
```

Comment: the result value is false.

Comment: Run the full query on mysql and check what is the specific error.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian And `confirm` field belongs to which table??

Comment: ok,I deleted it. I get this error : `Duplicate column name 'id'`

Comment: Try the updated query. Avoid to fetch fields those are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid the name 'current_user'. current_user is the Mysql default function. So, tried with othername like 'currentuser' or 'current_users'.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is possibly naming conflicts in the subquery.  Although without sample data, it could be almost anything -- bad table names and bad column names come to mind.

Start by getting rid of the subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(coupon_id), coupon_id, shadyab_profi, seri
FROM traction_details td INNER JOIN
     tractions t
     ON t.id = td.tr_id
WHERE (td.sell_start_date >= '2015-09-10 01:00:00') AND
       confirm = 2 AND
       td.adviser = 7
GROUP BY coupon_id, seri, shadyab_profit, seri
```

You should add appropriate table aliases to all the column names.  If any of these columns are ambiguous, then MySQL needs to know where they come from.

Comment: I got this message : `Column 'seri' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: @S.M_Emamian . . . Then add the appropriate table alias so it is not ambiguous.  Read the last paragraph in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is little point using a derived table with more columns that you are ultimately using. Just do the grouping directly on the tables without using an unnecessary subquery. **BUT** (as mentioned in another answer) you must include the appropriate table aliases on ALL column references (replace the T? as needed)

```
SELECT
      COUNT(T?.coupon_id) AS current_usr
    , T?.coupon_id
    , T?.shadyab_profit
    , T?.seri
FROM traction_details as TD
      INNER JOIN tractions as T ON TD.tr_id = T.id
WHERE TD.sell_start_date >= '2015-09-10 01:00:00'
      AND T?.confirm = 2
      AND TD.adviser = 7
GROUP BY
      T?.coupon_id
    , T?.seri
    , T?.shadyab_profit
```